# Export/Print list of GitHub repo issues

Tags: github

The repository that I am looking at has a great number of issues that I would like to read but it's not manageable while scrolling in GitHub interace. Is there an option to export or print a full list of issues for a repository?

Answer (score 15):

There is an [Issues API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/). To get all issues from a repo, you can use cURL:

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/username/reponame/issues
```

This returns a JSON encoded list of all issues. And …

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/username/reponame/issues?status=open
```

… returns all open issues. Now you just have to convert the JSON to CSV and you are set.

Comment: Thank you very much for drawing attention to existing GitHub API.

Comment: If the repository is private or you have 2-factor auth enabled, you can still get to this easily by going into Github and creating an application token, and using it like this: `curl -X GET -u yourapplicationtoken:x-oauth-basic https://api.github.com/repos/username/reponame/issues?state=all`

Comment: The application token for `curl -X GET -u yourapplicationtoken:x-oauth-basic https://api.github.com/repos/username/reponame/issues?state=all` must have the `repo` scope selected. Otherwise the permission is not granted and you get an 404 error.

Answer (score 5):

You can issue [`hub`](https://github.com/github/hub) command for that.

1. Clone the repo.
2. Install `hub` (e.g. on macOS run: `brew install hub`).
3. Run: `hub issue` in your repo directory to list the open issues (it's in Markdown format).

---

See: `hub --help` for more info:

```
These GitHub commands are provided by hub:

   pull-request   Open a pull request on GitHub
   fork           Make a fork of a remote repository on GitHub and add as remote
   create         Create this repository on GitHub and add GitHub as origin
   browse         Open a GitHub page in the default browser
   compare        Open a compare page on GitHub
   release        List or create releases (beta)
   issue          List or create issues (beta)
```

> `usage: git issue`
>
> List summary of the open issues for the project that the "origin" remote points to.

Note: Above reads `git issue`, because it expects that you've alias `hub` to `git` ([GH-966](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/966)), e.g.

```
alias git=hub
```

---

Other alternative is to use some tools such as: [IssuesDownload](https://github.com/psgs/IssuesDownload) (Java app), [export_repo_issues_to_csv.py](https://gist.github.com/unbracketed/3380407), etc.

Comment: This doesn't work. `issue` (or `issues`) is not a `hub` subcommand.

Comment: @whitequark I've got  hub 2.2.3 and it has `hub issue` command. See: [`help.go`](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/commands/help.go#L174).

Comment: Oh! I haven't realized hub was rewritten in go and was using the Ruby gem.

Answer (score 1):

I've cooked up this helper: https://runkit.io/fiatjaf/586a5b3110e9fd0014ff8aa7/branches/master/formspree/formspree?status=open which uses [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/).

Replace `formspree/formspree` with your own user and repository name. It is a [RunKit endpoint](https://runkit.com/docs/endpoint). The source code is at https://runkit.com/fiatjaf/586a5b3110e9fd0014ff8aa7.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [GitHub CSV Tools](https://github.com/gavinr/github-csv-tools#readme), it's a command line program that allows you to export the issues to CSV.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/146752)