# Is there a way to undelete GitHub issue labels?

Tags: github

I accidentally deleted an issues label in GitHub that was labelling several hundred issues. Is there a way to either undelete the label or at least find out which issues had previously been marked with the label?

What happened was that I couldn't see an assigned issue but I knew there was a filter. I thought "Manage labels" might be a likely thing to try so I pressed it. Having pressed it all the numbers went away so I thought, "hey if I click the checkbox besides the bug *label* then surely I'll be able to see all the bugs."

Except it wasn't a checkbox, it was a small circle around an **x** for delete. So now I've unmarked all our bugs.

Any ideas how we can restore those labels without having a day long meeting prioritizing our issues again?

Edit: Looks like we got lucky and everything should either be labelled as bug or enhancement. I'll be spending sometime this weekend poking the github api to create a script to add a bug label to everything that isn't an enhancement. At least that's more fun than sitting in a meeting. Thanks for the lesson even if it could have been very painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to undelete issue labels. Once gone, it's gone.

If you had [exported a backup of the issues](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45258/export-print-list-of-github-repo-issues) before removing the label(s) then you might be able to go back and reference that to find out which issues had what labels.

Answer (score 0):

In case the deletion was done recently, one can use the [Events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events) endpoint of the [GitHub REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

Look for the `labels` object and the content `name`. Then you will find the event and the context where the label was deleted. You can then restore it manually or [using the API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#update-an-issue).

(My own deletion was too long ago, no way to recover it)